# html/css text is not appearing inside the div

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to add "this is" text inside this white container as a heading and then a

tag as a short description of the person,

Currently this tag is inside the div but appearing outside,
i have no idea why,
Can anyone help...!

I am using simple html/css not any framework etc.
and
this is the css.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.box {
  height: 160px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.box img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  margin-left: 31px;
  margin-right: 349px;
  margin-bottom: 69px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Testing Person Card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> </head>
<section class="container" style="width: 1920px; height: 500px; background-color: gray; overflow: auto;">
  <div class="box"> <img src="images/person1.png" alt="Person1">
    <h1>this is</h1>
  </div>
</section>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: You should check it with your browser inspector, looks like the title is just simply below the picture (`height` and `margin-bottom`)

Comment: @Shehrooz Don't comment the HTML, edit your original post and include it there.

Comment: @pso edited and html added

Answer (score 1):

You can set your image as a background image. After that, you can center vertically and horizontally your `h1` element in the box.

Here is an example:

```css
.box {
  height: 160px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  
  /*Background Image Properties*/
  background-image: url('https://apk4all.com/wp-content/uploads/apps/Sagon-Circle-Icon-Pack-Dark-UI/EEbkBvCkmjhYr0xIfkCAEoN3cWVChd6Fh7tC5jfRS06MU0_8mMBwx9yTOHAnO_Hzp40-2.png');
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /*Center the text in the box*/
  text-align: center;
  
}

h1{
transform: translateY(60px);
}
```

```html
<section class="container" style="width: 1920px; height: 500px; background-color: gray; overflow: auto;">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>this is</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

*I have Solved Your Question*
*For Demo Run code snippet*

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.boximg {
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.box h1 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
.box p {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section
      class="container"
      style="width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: gray; overflow: auto"
    >
      <div class="box">
        <img class="boximg" src="https://i.ibb.co/nkcb8Rt/img.jpg" alt="Person1" />
        <h1>This is Title</h1>
        <p>
          My Name is xyz. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
          elit. Incidunt enim numquam impedit cumque placeat quibusdam iusto cum
          saepe sit unde nemo totam aliquid, sapiente animi alias obcaecati
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No magic happens. Your content simply does not fit inside your `div`. Sum of margins of your elements plus image height are greater than `height` of your `div`. Default `DIV` overflow is `visible`, so content looks as if it was placed outside.

To ensure content never overflows its parent element, you can change `overflow` property of the parent element. For example, you can temporary set `overflow:auto` on your `div`. This will automatically show scroll bars for your content.

You can fix it by reducing `margin-bottom` of your image or by increasing height of your `div`.

Answer (score -1):

You can adjust by margin with position relative.

```
element.style {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Add threw percentage instead of px to make it little bit responsive :-)

Comment: Your answer is not very universal. And it's not the best practice.

Comment: This code is not also universal.
I just give him simple solution without changing they html code. So its time saving solution.